# how to make null values last while sorting in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(customer.customerName));

By using above one i'm getting only customerNames but i want also get who don't have the customerName(null).

Comment: I guess they are filtered somehow before. Would you like to provide the whole criteria? Or at least the part where `customer` comes from.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk yes we are filtering the asc/desc order but i need to get both the customer name as well as customer names are null

Comment: You didn't get. I guess the customers with name of null are filtered before (probably, you need an `outer join` instead of `(inner) join`. If you remove the ordering, the result wouldn't be different, right?